# iPhoneでvideoのサムネイルを表示させる方法

Tags: monaca, jquery, html5, cordova

MonacaクラウドでiPhone向けのアプリを試作中です。

cordovaのcaptureVideoを使って取得した動画を、標準アプリの写真のように
動画のカットをサムネイル表示させクリックすると再生させたいと思っています。
表示される動画のカットは1フレーム目などで構いません。
外部サイトに動画を送信せず、ローカルだけで処理したいと考えています。
最終的にはiPhoneだけでなくAndroidでも動作させたいと思っています。

videoタグを使いましたが、一度再生するまではサムネイルが表示されません。

videoタグで何とかサムネイルを表示させる、ローカルでサムネイルを作成する、別の動画再生プラグインを使うなど、何かしら方法がありましたらお教え頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323053/dynamically-using-the-first-frame-as-poster-in-html5-video

こんな方法（Popcorn.jsのプラグイン）があるようですが、Crossdomainで使えないのが難点なようです。

[rwaldron/popcorn.capture](https://github.com/rwaldron/popcorn.capture)

Comment: ありがとうございます！良さそうな感じですが、Popcorn自体使ったことがなく、試していますが確認に時間がかかりそうです。取り急ぎご報告まで